# Why is it not OK to pass `char **` to a function that takes a `const char **` in C?

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I convert ‘char**’ to a ‘const char* const*’ in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78125/why-cant-i-convert-char-to-a-const-char-const-in-c)

I am curious, why can't I pass a `char **` to `const char **` function? Where as it is OK to pass `char *` to a `const char *` function it seems not to be OK to do it with double pointers. I thought it was always ok to add constness (but not ok to drop constness) but now it seems I have been wrong.

Gcc compiler is giving me the errror:

```
note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
int f(const char **a) { }

int main() {
    char *a;
    f(&a);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This appears to be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78125/why-cant-i-convert-char-to-a-const-char-const-in-c

Comment: BTW, to people voting to close: this isn't an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78125/why-cant-i-convert-char-to-a-const-char-const-in-c since that one is specifically about `const char* const*`. (Some of the answers there are relevant, however.)

Answer (score 18):

Because the compiler can't guarantee safety.

See Q11.10 from the comp.lang.c FAQ: [Why can't I pass a `char **` to a function which expects a `const char **`?](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html)

> suppose you performed the following more complicated series of
>   assignments:
>
> ```
> const char c = 'x';    /* 1 */
> char *p1;              /* 2 */
> const char **p2 = &p1; /* 3 */
> *p2 = &c;              /* 4 */
> *p1 = 'X';             /* 5 */
> ```
>
> In line 3, we assign a `char **` to a `const char **`. (The compiler should complain.) In line 4, we assign a `const char *` to a `const char *`; this is clearly legal. In line 5, we modify what a `char *` points to--this is supposed to be legal. However, `p1` ends up pointing to `c`, which is `const`. This came about in line 4, because `*p2` was really `p1`. This was set up in line 3, which is an assignment of a form that is disallowed, and this is exactly why line 3 is disallowed.
>
> Assigning a `char **` to a `const char **` (as in line 3, and in the original question) is not immediately dangerous. But it sets up a situation in which `p2`'s promise--that the ultimately-pointed-to value won't be modified--cannot be kept.

Comment: This is wrong: "In line 4, we assign a const char * to a const char *; this is clearly legal." `*p2` is a `char*` and `&c` is a `const char*`. In the statement `*p2 = &c` there is an assignment of a `const char*` to `char*` this is not legal without a constant cast.

Comment: @JonathanMee No. `p2` is of type `const char**`; it is a pointer to a pointer to a `char` constant. `*p2` is of type  `const char*`.

Comment: Ugh, you're right. It's line 3 that 's the problem. It seems like preventing that would really solve the problem...

Comment: @JonathanMee Yes, and that is why line 3 is disallowed. =)