# C++ forbidden pointer to pointer conversion

Tags: c++, pointers, type-conversion

In C++, `Type **` to `Type const **` conversion is forbidden. Also, conversion from `derived **` to `Base **` is not allowed.

Why are these conversions wtong ? Are there other examples where pointer to pointer conversion cannot happen ?

Is there a way to work around: how to convert a pointer to pointer to a non-const object of type `Type` to a pointer to pointer to const object of type `Type`, since `Type **` --> `Type const **` does not make it ?

Comment: Why *should* it be allowed? You cannot in general convert a `U*` to a `W*`, because that makes no sense...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it not OK to pass \`char \*\*\` to a function that takes a \`const char \*\*\` in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496000/why-is-it-not-ok-to-pass-char-to-a-function-that-takes-a-const-char-in)

Comment: i wanted to draw parallel between two conversion bans, which is not the point of the thread you mentionned. WIM, I am asking what other conversion bans are alike.

Comment: Duplicate Q is in C, not C++. But C++ has only tightened the type system rules, so the ban still stands for the same reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Type *` to `const Type*` is allowed:

```
Type t;
Type *p = &t;
const Type*q = p;
```

`*p` can be modified through `p` but not through `q`.

If `Type **` to `const Type**` conversion were allowed, we may have

```
const Type t_const;

Type* p;
Type** ptrtop = &p;

const Type** constp = ptrtop ; // this is not allowed
*constp = t_const; // then p points to t_const, right ?

p->mutate(); // with mutate a mutator, 
// that can be called on pointer to non-const p
```

The last line may alter `const t_const` !

For the `derived **` to `Base **` conversion, problem occurs when `Derived1` and `Derived2` types derive from same `Base`. Then,

```
Derived1 d1;
Derived1* ptrtod1 = &d1;
Derived1** ptrtoptrtod1 = &ptrtod1 ;

Derived2 d2;
Derived2* ptrtod2 = &d2;

Base** ptrtoptrtobase = ptrtoptrtod1 ;
*ptrtoptrtobase  = ptrtod2 ;
```

and a `Derived1 *` points to a `Derived2`.

Right way to make a `Type **` a pointer to pointer to a const is to make it a `Type const* const*`.

Comment: The variable names are unfortunately really unreadable. Simply replacing `ptrto` by `p` should actually help.

Comment: Wouldn't `*ptrtoptrtobase  = ptrtod2 ;` cause slicing anyway? (I dont't know if assigning with pointers to the parent class produces slicing)