# Why does `execvp` take a `char *const argv[]`?

Tags: c, exec, api

I'm wondering if there is a reason between two exec functions differing in `const`-ness, of if this is just a bug in the Single Unix Spec:

Excerpting from the Linux manpage, which appears to align with the [Single Unix Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fexecve.html), here are a two versions of `exec`:

> `int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...);
>
> int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);`

`execlp` takes its arguments as `const char *`, and it takes two or more of them. `const` in C is a promise that the function will not change the pointed-to data, in this case the actual characters (`char`) that make up the string.

`execvp` instead takes its arguments as an array of pointers. However, instead of an array of pointers to `const char *` as you'd expect, the `const` keyword is in a different spot—and this matters quite a bit to C. `execvp` is saying it may well modify the characters in the strings, but it promises not to modify the array—that is, the pointers to the strings. So, in other words,

```c
int fake_execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]) {
    argv[0] = "some other string"; /* this is an error */
    argv[0][0] = 'f';              /* change first letter to 'f': this is perfectly OK! */
    /* ⋮ */
}
```

In particular, this makes it hard (technically, prohibited) to call execvp using C++'s `std::string`'s `to_cstr()` method, which returns `const char *`.

It seems like `execvp` really ought to take `const char *const argv[]`, in other words, it ought to promise not to do either of the above changes.

Comment: Why it is migrated if it already has an accepted answer??

Comment: Because it belongs here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To quote the page you link:

> The statement about `argv[]` and `envp[]` being constants is included to
>   make explicit to future writers of language bindings that these
>   objects are completely constant. Due to a limitation of the ISO C
>   standard, it is not possible to state that idea in standard C.
>   Specifying two levels of `const`- qualification for the `argv[]` and
>   `envp[]` parameters for the exec functions may seem to be the natural
>   choice, given that these functions do not modify either the array of
>   pointers or the characters to which the function points, but this
>   would disallow existing correct code.

Basically the `const` qualification on `execlp` and `execvp` are completely compatible in the sense that they specify identical limitations on the corresponding arguments.

Comment: *(Edit: Ignore this. my point has been directly discussed already in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496000/why-is-it-not-ok-to-pass-char-to-a-function-that-takes-a-const-char-in?rq=1)).*

The table near the bottom of that linked page [1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fexecve.html) is very surprising for me.  I didn't realize in C that is wasn't possible to initialize a `const char * const *` with a `char * const *`.  This works fine in C++.  I can't really see why.  Why does C consider these two types to be incompatible?