# C/C++ typecasting convert int** to const int**

Tags: c++, casting, compiler-errors, int, type-conversion

Consider the following code snippet.

```
int** ptr;  // memory pointed by ptr is initialized to its content.
const int** ptrConst;
ptrConst = ptr // Now I want to convert it type of const int**
```

It gives compilation error conversion loses qualifier.

Please suggest an alternative to achieve it.

Comment: As you can see from the linked dupe this is potentially risky, and in any case you might want to consider moving away from multiple indirection, there's usually better ways of handling this in C++.

Comment: The reason why that is now allowed is explained in [Question 11.10 of the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html). Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `const_cast`.

```
ptrConst = const_cast<const int**>(ptr);
```

You may wish to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055655/double-pointer-const-correctness-warnings-in-c) question for information on why this is not a good idea.

Comment: And what should it be like in C?