# Why is an implicit conversion from non-const to const allowed for pointers in the first place?

Tags: c, pointers, const-correctness

I understand that implicit conversion from `non-const` to `const` is not dangerous when handling values, by example:

```
int mutable = 5;
const int immutable = mutable;
```

However, when working with pointers, I can do something as follows:

```
int some_number = 5;
int *mutable = &some_number;
const int *immutable = mutable;    // <= Legal, but isn't it dangerous?

// Let's try to break const
printf("%d\n", *immutable);        // Prints 5
mutable[0] = 10;
printf("%d\n", *immutable);        // Prints 10
```

By the way, for double pointers this is not allowed (at least you get a warning)! See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055655/double-pointer-const-correctness-warnings-in-c) question and the references therein.

Comment: The common use-case for pointers to constants are as function arguments. This tells the users of the function (as well as the compiler) that the function will not alter the data that the pointer points to.

Comment: Your example doesn't "break const" because the object that was modified (`some_number`) is not const. Having const on a pointer target doesn't mean "guaranteed to yield the same value if you read it twice, with some other stuff happening in between"

Comment: Think of `const` as promise. Why any one want to break his own promise?

Comment: There is no `const` qualified pointer in your code!

Comment: @Olaf: that is not the point, it's about the changing of the underlying values

Comment: @Nibor: Read the title!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the C11 standard (draft N1570)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> #### 6.7.3 Type qualifiers
>
> Syntax
>
> 1. type-qualifier:
>      `const`
>      `restrict`
>      `volatile`
>      `_Atomic`
>
> [...]
>
> Semantics:
>
> 4. The properties associated with qualified types are meaningful only for expressions that are lvalues.
>
> [...]
>
> EXAMPLE 1
>
> An object declared
>
> ```
> extern const volatile int real_time_clock;
> ```
>
> may be modifiable by hardware, but cannot be assigned to, incremented, or decremented.

In simple terms:

`const` doesn't mean a value never changes. It only means that *you* are not allowed to change it<sup>1</sup>.

For *callees* , `const` is a restriction, not a promise.
For *callers* however, it *is* a promise. Passing a `const` pointer to a function, you can safely assume that the function will not change your data<sup>2</sup>, thus is "making a promise to you".

---

<sup>1</sup> ...through the identifier with the `const` qualifier.
<sup>2</sup> ...through the `const` argument passed to it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use C99, but I guess the standard there is similar. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: But it's strange that for double pointers, a warning is issued indeed, to prevent what I just did above for single pointers, see http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html

Comment: "It only means that you are not allowed to change it." - Not even that! I means **the programmer** guarantees not to modify it.

Comment: @Nibor: C is not `const`-safe across multiple indirections like C++ is. It allows certain constructs which are indeed problematic. But as it is a guarantee by the programmer, it is at your side to not break that contract.

Comment: *Passing a const pointer to a function, you can safely assume that the function will not change your data, thus is "making a promise to you"* This is not correct, the function may still change the data via other parameters of global values.

Comment: @2501 My example says nothing about such connections though, only about a `const` value being passed to a function, and the function being unable to change the underlying value through that argument. In a way, it is implicitly assuming the absence of such a connection in the same way it is assuming the function not to violate the specification, the hardware to function as expected, and the laws of physics to hold. I was hoping these didn't require explicit declaration.

Comment: That is not what is written in the answer. Your comment adds: *through that argument*, which is an important distinction.

Comment: The const may still be legally cast away, so this is really not a guarantee.

Comment: @2501: If you cast away `const` and then modify the data pointed at, you get undefined behaviour.  You can cast away the const-ness of a character literal all you like, but if your system places them in read-only (`text`) memory, it does you no good if you try to modify the data pointed at.

Comment: The statement _It only means that you are not allowed to change it_ should be qualified with _via the `const`-qualified pointer_ or something similar.  You can change the data pointed at via a pointer that is not `const`-qualified (`mutable` in the question), or via the original (non-`const`) variable name (`some_number` in the question).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The function that receives the const pointer doesn't know if the how the object was defined. *If you cast away const and then modify the data pointed at, you get undefined behaviour.* Not exactly. It is only undefined if the object, the const pointer is pointing to, was defined with const.