# What's correct pointer type?

Tags: c, c99

I have C99 code like this (but not exactly this one, below is just example to demonstrate the problem):

```
// file: const.c

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct MyData {
    int value;
};

struct MyData **createRandomData(size_t n)
{
    assert(n > 0);
    struct MyData **result = calloc(n, sizeof(struct MyData *));
    assert(result != NULL);
    for (size_t i =0 ; i < n; ++i) {
        result[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct MyData));
        assert(result[i] != NULL);
        result[i]->value = rand();
    }
    return result;
}

void freeData(struct MyData* data[], size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        free(data[i]);
    }
    free(data);
}

int isMyDataSumCanBeDividedByX(const struct MyData* data[], size_t n, int x)
{
    long long sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        sum += data[i]->value;
    }
    return sum % x == 0;
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    const size_t n = rand() % 100 + 1;
    const int x = rand() % 10 + 2;
    struct MyData **data = createRandomData(n);
    const int result = isMyDataSumCanBeDividedByX(data, n, x);
    printf("%s\n", result ? "found it!" : "not found...");
    freeData(data, n);
    return result;
}
```

When I am trying to compile this:
    gcc -std=c99 const.c
I am getting following warning:

```
const.c: In function ‘main’:
const.c:46:51: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘isMyDataSumCanBeDividedByX’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     const int result = isMyDataSumCanBeDividedByX(data, n, x);
                                                   ^~~~
const.c:31:5: note: expected ‘const struct MyData **’ but argument is of type ‘struct MyData **’
 int isMyDataSumCanBeDividedByX(const struct MyData* data[], size_t n, int x)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I know I can do just a typecast to solve this, but I want to understand, what correct type of parameter data should be, so that:

- It can accept struct MyData ** without this warning.
- Do not allow modification of MyData content (i.e. contain const )

Can anyone please explain why warning is generated and hot to get rid of it not by using typecast but by using correct pointer types?

Comment: well, you ask how to make it accept `struct MyData **` without the warning - and the answer is: you can't, not if you don't allow the modification of `MyData` content.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055655/double-pointer-const-correctness-warnings-in-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/44166/

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, but I didn't know it is not allowed at all. Thank you for links with explanations. So only typecast will help.

Comment: `int isMyDataSumCanBeDividedByX(const struct MyData* const *data, size_t n, int x)`

Comment: @Balmar, what you suggest likely works in C++, but doesn't work in C, and I'm asking about C. C doesn't allow this at all.

Comment: Try `int isMyDataSumCanBeDividedByX(struct MyData* const *data, size_t n, int x)`.  The elements pointed to by `data` are `const`

Comment: @ivan.ukr even the type cast is not really correct.

Comment: Alas it is the *C++* question that explains the C thing in depth...

Comment: @Antti Haapala , I understand that typecast is not really correct, but I need something that let me compile code like this. So in my real program I've ended up with declaring function parameter as "const struct MyData * const *" and casting to that when calling. A bit ugly, but safer.