# Best way to pass a string array to a function imposing const-ness in all levels down

Tags: c, pointers, constants

In C we cannot assign a `char**` to `const char *const *` because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5055789/1841194). So, what's the base way to declare a function accepting an array of strings?

My input parameters may be of any types, including:

- `char **`
- `const char **`
- ...

Comment: `char **` cannot be assigned to `const char **` but `const char **` can be assigned to `const char  * const *`...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, I know, but my input parameter is of different types, including `char **` and `const char **`, so I need a function to accept both.

Comment: Best way would be to just accept `const char * const *` and then those using `char **` need an explicit cast, or you could hide the cast behind a `_Generic` selection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up using the [Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918959/antti-haapala)'s suggestion (thank you [Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918959/antti-haapala)!). Using `const char * const *` as the argument type and explicitly casting incompatible types.

```
#define STR_ARR(v) _Generic((v),             \ 
    char**: (const char *const *)(v),        \
    char *const *: (const char *const *)(v), \
    default: (v))

void foo(const char * const * strings);
```

Usage:

```
char **strs1;
foo(STR_ARR(strs1));

const char **strs2;
foo(STR_ARR(strs2));
```

Comment: You shouldn't allow a default clause. And I'd use a wrapper macro around the specific function instead, then in API documentation use the macro name instead of the actual function name.

Comment: @Lundin I don't think the default clause causes a problem as the other types will be checked by the compiler. I only whitelisted the required types.

Comment: There's a scary amount of C programmers that follow the rule "when in doubt cast to void pointer". So `foo((void*)my_wildly_incompatible_misaligned_pointer);` is a likely scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to have the caller sort their code out. Otherwise you can do a type-safe wrapper macro along the lines of this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void str_print_ro (const char* str_arr[], size_t n)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    puts(str_arr[i]);
  }
}

#define str_print(arr,n) _Generic((arr), \
  const char** : str_print_ro,           \
  char**       : str_print_ro) ((const char**)(arr), n) 

int main (void)
{
  char* arr[] = {"hello", "world"};
  str_print(arr, sizeof arr/sizeof *arr);  
}
```

It probably doesn't make much sense to const-qualify the pointers themselves. If you for some reason need that too, then `const char* const str_arr[]` should sort it, and that one can be converted to from `char**` and `const char**` both.