# why using const when passing arguments gives me a warning?

Tags: c, function, pointers, constants

Why this code give me a warning says: passing argument 1 of "test" from incompatible pointer type? I know it's about the const before char **, but why?

```
void test(const int ** a)
{
}
int main()
{
    int a=0;
    int *b=&a;
    int **c=&b;
    test(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I convert 'char**' to a 'const char* const*' in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78125/why-cant-i-convert-char-to-a-const-char-const-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't assign an `int **` to a `const int **`, because if you did so, the latter pointer would allow you to give an `int *` variable the address of a `const int` object:

```
const int myconst = 10;
int *intptr;
const int **x = &intptr;    /* This is the implicit conversion that isn't allowed */
*x = &myconst;              /* Allowed because both *x and &myconst are const int * ... */
/* ... but now intptr points at myconst, and you could try to modify myconst through it */
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const int **
```

is a pointer to a pointer to a const int, but you are passing a pointer to a pointer to an int

I think you may want to declare test with `int ** const`, which says that the pointer is const and not the value.

NOTE: and I think this should be put in every question regarding pointers in C: cdecl.org is a pretty nice way of giving a human-readable expression

Answer (score 0):

The second answer to this question might be helpful:

[Why can't I convert 'char**' to a 'const char* const*' in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78125/why-cant-i-convert-char-to-a-const-char-const-in-c)

Unfortunately the accepted answer is not very good and does nothing to explain the reason.

Comment: Answer display order is randomized now, and the owner can change which answer is accepted, so you might want to clarify which answers you refer to.  Also I would say that question is not particularly relevant anyway: this question asks about the case of converting `int **` to `const int **` (note the lack of second `const`)