# double pointer to constant array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

Let us assume the following C (edit only C, not C++) function that performs a matrix-matrix multiplication from two matrices A,B and stores the result in new allocated memory (C):

```
double **MatrixMult(double **A, int rowA, int colA, double **B, int rowB, int colB)
{
    double **C = createEmptyMatrix(rowA, colB);
    int i; int j; int k;
    for (i=0;i<rowA;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<colB;j++)
        {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for (k=0;k<rowB;k++)
                C[i][j] += (A[i][k]*B[k][j]);
        }
    }
    return C;
}
```

Matrices A and B  are created as follows:

```
    double **A = createEmptyMatrix(10,10);
    double **B = createEmptyMatrix(10,10);
```

with the function

```
double **createEmptyMatrix(int rows,int cols)
{
    int i;
    double **L;
    L = (double **) malloc(rows*sizeof(double *));
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        L[i] = (double *) malloc(cols*sizeof(double));
    }
    return L;
}
```

Now, I try to use the SAME function to multiply a constant array (matrix) like

```
const double A_const[7][9] =  {
                                  {1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1,6.1,7.1,8.1,9.1},
                                  {1.2,2.2,3.2,4.2,5.2,6.2,7.2,8.2,9.2},
                                  {1.3,2.3,3.3,4.3,5.3,6.3,7.3,8.3,9.3},
                                  {1.4,2.4,3.4,4.4,5.4,6.4,7.4,8.4,9.4},
                                  {1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1,6.1,7.1,8.1,9.1},
                                  {1.2,2.2,3.2,4.2,5.2,6.2,7.2,8.2,9.2},
                                  {1.3,2.3,3.3,4.3,5.3,6.3,7.3,8.3,9.3}
                              };
```

with a non constant matrix B (dimension and content of A_const are chosen by random).

Basically, I try to pass a const array of doubles to a function that assumes `double**` as an argument.

I would like to avoid changing the definition of the function "MatrixMult". So, is it possible to define a ** (double pointer) to a constant array?

Comment: There is no such thing as C/C++ - they are two separate languages. Pick one (this is most likely C)

Comment: Can you explain what C/C++ is?

Comment: Also since you aren't modifying the passed in parameters in the function they should be declared as `const` anyway (e.g.: `const double **A` and `const double **B`) which may fix your problem (not sure, since you haven't described it in enough detail)

Comment: You absolutely cannot use the same function with an array. A double pointer is not the same thing as a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: Even though this code may compile in C and C++ the best answers differ.  Choose 1 language as the dual language tags attracts down-votes.

Comment: `double **` is not an array or a matrix. It can also not point to a matrix (aka 2D array). Why not use a 2D array, but the more complicated and problematic `double **`?

Comment: The C answer: Distinguish pointer and array. The C++ answer: We use classes. The "C/C++" answer: STOP pretending there is something called "C/C++"!

Comment: "I would like to avoid changing the definition of the function "MatrixMult"" - Your parameters demands a pointers to pointers to `double`. You currently have native arrays of arrays on the caller side, not pointers to pointers.  We don't know what you're *trying* to pass because the *caller* side of the actual invoke was never provided in your posted code.

Comment: Since the matrices (2D arrays) become very large i'd like to avoid doubling the memory requirements when calling the function

Comment: You should probably assert that `colA == rowB`, or otherwise detect shape mismatches. You might do better with a function signature `void MatrixMultiply(int rowA, int colArowB, int colB, double A[rowA][colArowB], double B[colArowB][colB], double C[rowA][colB])` where the calling code takes care of allocating the space.  However, this is using true matrices, not the `double **` variant that you start with, so it requires major changes.  Yes, this is using C99 and 'variable length array' (VLA) notation.  Yes, you can dynamically allocate those arrays.

Comment: What about the memory footprint of your suggested change?
Does the function create a copy of the matrices A and B when called?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of pointers to each row of your 2D array:

```
double *A_const_p[] = { A_const[0], A_const[1], 
                        A_const[2], A_const[3], 
                        A_const[4], A_const[5], A_const[6]};
```

Then you can pass this array to `MatrixMult`.

Note however that you'll need to remove the `const` qualifier from `A_const` if you don't want to change the function definition.

You also can't change the function to accept a `const double **` because a `double **` cannot be passed in for this parameter.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78125/why-cant-i-convert-char-to-a-const-char-const-in-c) for details.

Comment: I thought of this way before. But i assume that the memory requirements (for the pointer array) are added to those of the constant matrix?!

Comment: @boschika: yes, but that is unavoidable since your function requires an array of pointers, and that means you have to store the pointers somewhere in an array, separate from the array(s) of values.